# Invoke another program, assign task to a thread in it and return

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am writing a C++ program which will be invoked by another program. My program flow is something like the following image:

[image]

**Program Description:** The `program-1` will Periodically call the `program-2` (in approx. every 30 seconds). The only task of the `program-2` is to Write the data but I do not want to block the program-1 to wait while the data is getting written. Therefore, I want to assign the task of writing data to another thread and immediately come out of the `Program-2`.

**Question:** How should I implement a thread in `Program-2` so that it does not block the `program-1`?

**PS:** The data needs to be written to the same file every time.

Comment: The second program is a typical server. It shoulld have a job queue, a thread that communicates with the outside world, and one or more worker threads. The comm thread writes jobs to the queue and worker threads retrieve the jobs and execute them. The queue should be synchronised. In your situation it is probably the best to keep one worker thread.

Comment: "How do I control the creation of Threads ...?", "How do I make sure that the previous thread is still not writing the XML file ..." - This is all about **process interaction**, where one process represents the `Program-1` and another process represents the `Program-2`. Currently you have only one process interaction, when `Program-1` runs the `Program-2` (and passes arguments to it). So you need to elaborate ways for other interactions. As n.m. noted, you may setup network connection between the processes. But other variants are also avaiable: POSIX message queues, shared memory, etc.

Comment: `How do I control the creation of Threads in this situation?` You don't control **creation**, you **synchronize** threads. One common approach is to use a multiple producer, single consumer queue. All threads write messages to a queue and only one thread consumes them and writes them to the file in order. Another 
(simplier but less scalable) approach is to simply lock the file for the duration of data saving.

Comment: I have reformulated my question. Please reopen it ( or let me know if I need to add some more information to it).

Answer (score 1):

If saving the data takes more time than produce it then you will have to write it in another file in parallel, you have no choice because even buffering the data will cause the buffer grow and grow indefinitely.

If this is not the case then you don't need a separated thread in program-2, read all the data first and then write it to the file every time.